# Youtube API v3 - where is the flag for adult/nsfw?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

[Google API v3 docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

I've tried requesting for all 13 "parts" and none of them gave me a flag to say if the returned video is NSFW/R-rated.

Is that unavailable in this api?

Answer (score 0):

Ah found it.

**contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating**

only valid value is: **ytAgeRestricted**

apparently that section doesn't come back on non-age-restricted videos, which is why I never saw it.